# JSONParser: Unexpected token COLON(:)

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a json file with JSONParse and am getting this error, with the error occurring in beginning of the following json:

Unexpected token COLON(:) at position 11.

```
{"276716878": {
  "followers": [
    2435018580,
    1664252310,
    372262434
   ],
  "following": [
    16211434,
    945440959,
    130682467,
    264257750,
    900526363,
    318231688,
    40335029,
    64044676
   ]
}}
```

I also wrote the json file with the following:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(JSON_FILE);
        out.write(json.toString(1));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Comment: Try putting your JSON in some online JSON formatter and see if it gives some errors.

Comment: The character at position 11 is a double quote, not a colon. My guess is that what you're parsing is not what you posted. Check your file.

Comment: It works fine on the online JSON formatters

Comment: The fragment in your question is not complete, valid JSON.  Please edit your question and include the smallest, **complete**, and exact JSON text that still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There could be some format error in the json string you passed. [Validate your json string](http://jsonlint.com/). The below sample code works fine.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

    private static final String JSON_FILE = "/home/visruth/Desktop/Visruth.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jsonText = "{\"215876567\": { \"followers\": [ 2464054938, 772677937]}}";

        try (

        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(JSON_FILE);

        ) {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

            int indentFactor = 1;
            String prettyprintedJSON = json.toString(indentFactor);
            System.out.println(prettyprintedJSON);
            out.write(prettyprintedJSON);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Assign your json text in `jsonText` variable and try.

Comment: I have a valid JSON, but the error arises when I try to parse the json file with a JSONParser.

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    FileReader file = new FileReader(JSON_FILE);
    Object obj = parser.parse(file);
    json = (JSONObject) obj;

Comment: @natc221 can you post that complete json string in the question?

Comment: @natc221 what is the package name of JSONParser?

Comment: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Also added the complete string in question

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring classes from different apis for this purpose. Just use only one api.

Here is a demo code which works fine with the given json string in the question.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCase { 

    private static final String JSON_FILE = "/home/visruth/Desktop/Visruth.txt";

    @Test
    public void testJSONParser() throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try (

                FileWriter out = new FileWriter(JSON_FILE);

                ) {

            String jsonText = "{\"276716878\": { \"followers\": [  2435018580, 1664252310, 372262434  ], \"following\": [ 16211434, 945440959, 130682467, 264257750, 900526363,  318231688, 40335029, 64044676 ] }}";

            Object obj = parser.parse(jsonText);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


            JSONObject jsonObject215876567 = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("276716878");

            JSONArray followers = (JSONArray)(jsonObject215876567.get("followers"));

            Assert.assertEquals("[2435018580,1664252310,372262434]", followers.toString());

            String jsonStringFromJsonObject = jsonObject.toString();// There is no argument as an int           

            out.write(jsonStringFromJsonObject);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```